# Продолжить выполнение программы после ошибки

Tags: python, chromedriver

У меня есть код который парсит web-морду роутера. Я использую chromedriver. Иногда бывает что страница роутера не грузится из-за отключения света и программа, когда ей не удается открыть страницу, завершает выполнение. Как можно отловить эту ошибку и продолжить выполнение, пытался сделать это через try except, но я не знаю какое исключение должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Если не знаешь какая именно ошибка нужна для отлова и тебе не особо это надо, а лишь просто хочешь чтобы дальше работала программа, то можно просто так:

```
try:
    # тут код который надо чтобы пытался выполнить
except:
    # тут код, который всегда работает и нет ошибок
```

Например:

```
try:
    print(7/0)
except:
    print('Что-то пошло не так...')
```

Comment: то есть я могу и в try и в expect кинуть один и тот же код?

Comment: в **except** как правило, пишут 100% рабочий код, т.к. он должен выполниться в случае ошибки.

Comment: да, спасибо, вроде бы разобрался с проблемой